# How to insert filename from cell into excel formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, csv

I have a bunch of .csv files that have IDs that I am trying to insert into a formula. The IDs are all listed in column F. Here is F in my sheet:

```
F
701
684
128
701
485
701
...
```

Each CSV file is in a folder and titled the exact contents of F plus .csv so "701.csv" "684.csv" etc. Here is the formula I am trying but is not working:

```vb
=VLOOKUP(D1, F1 & '.csv'!$B:$C,2)
```

This formula works fine if I replace the "F1 & '.csv'" portion with just the ID like so:

```vb
=VLOOKUP(D1, '701.csv'!$B:$C,2)
```

But I don't want to have to manually enter the ID for every single row (there's hundreds of rows).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are missing double and single quotations. It should be something like `"'"&F1&".csv'!$B:$C"`

Comment: Not sure what I did wrong but still get an error using: `=VLOOKUP(D2,"'"&F2&".csv'!$B:$C",2)`. Also tried doing the full directory and still error: `=VLOOKUP(D2,"'C:\Users\person\Desktop\ub\CF\AS\["&F2&".csv]"&F2&"'!$B:$C",2)`

Comment: not sure why your hardcoded one works, seems like you may also be missing the sheet name in there. But maybe excel doesn't need sheet names when working with .csv files.

Comment: @gns100 If you are building a reference by assembling text + cell references, you have to use the INDIRECT function.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are going to need an INDIRECT function call to get Excel to understand what you are trying to do.

`=VLOOKUP(D1,INDIRECT("'"&F1&".csv'!$B:$C"),2)`

If you use a formula to derive the text string, rather than a static string, you will usually have to use INDIRECT().  This includes *any* use of concatenation.

Be aware that INDIRECT is a volatile function, meaning it is recalculated with every change in the worksheet, and can cause sluggish performance in large sheets.